# Joomla open graph plugins all use "meta name" instead of "meta property" - how to change?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, joomla, facebook-opengraph

I've been trying for a while to get open graph into my joomla 3 site. I've used almost all the joomla plugins available and facebook still can't read anything I post.

The plugins all seem to be using *meta name* like so: meta name="og:title" meta name="og:type" meta name="og:url" meta name="og:site_name" meta name="og:description" 
but facebook wants them to use *meta description*. I've scoured index files in my back end, asked my web hosts, a few programmer friends, looked at the answers to similar topics on many different forums and really can't find anything that tells me *HOW* I can change those to read "meta description". I vaguely understand it to be a joomla thing that it says name rather than the plugins but either way, I'm not sure how to deal.

Does any one know how I can change that?

Comment: Do any of the other users using these plugins report this problem? If not Id guess that it is probably something simple. Did you ask on the support sites for the plugins?

Comment: yes, they say it is a joomla thing to default to name vs. property and not something the plugin controls...

Comment: So they say their joomla plugin doesn't work in joomla? That doesn't make much sense.  As you can see it looks as the the names are given. I see the word description for example.  I hink you are mixing up what "meta name" means (the string you showed indicatates that the sames are site_name, description, url, title, type) and what you think you want (meta site_name, meta description, meta url, meta title, meta type).  Do you see? I think the issue is probably something with how you are connecting. Are you coding this or are you using a plugin that is just supposed to work?

Answer (score 1):

I tried almoust all plugins too and at the end of the day i code something by myself.
But remember:

If you got Gzip Compression tunred on, facebook/linkedin istn able to read your data! For theese hosts you need to turn of Gzip! ...You can do this in template:

```
    $unsupported = false;
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
    $pattern = strtolower('/facebookexternalhit|LinkedInBot/x');
    if (preg_match($pattern, strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))){
        $unsupported = true;
    }
}
if (($app->get('gzip') == 1) && $unsupported){
    $app->set('gzip', 0);
}
```